# asp.net response.redirect avoid validation

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET form which has many requiredfield validators. Now under some consditions , I have to choose response.redirect to go to another form (this happens when a menu item is chosen under some complex conditions). In this case the navigation fails because of Requiredfield validators on the current form.

Any Idea how I can solve this

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `CausesValidation` property to false on the relevant control?
Or alternatively, you could do the redirection client-side.